# FSL Lunch Break

Tags: salesforce

I have tried the below approaches but none have created automated lunch breaks in FSL dispatch console -

1. Added break timings in Work Rule - Field Service- Resource Availability.
2. Tried adding break timings in Work Rule Entry.

In the FSL Settings I have below settings set to true -
Use enhanced scheduling and optimization for all service territories
Calculate travel and breaks

Answer (score 0):

When you're adding Break Rule Entry records to a Work Rule, ensure that you leave the Break Start and Duration fields within the Scheduling Policy Work Rule empty.

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.pfs_optimization_theory_work_rule_entry_service_resource_availability.htm&language=en_US&type=5

Let me know if that works.